# Will Rundeck kill scripts that it thinks are taking too long?

Tags: php, bash, rundeck

I have a rundeck job with a script workflow step that has some simple commands, like the following.

```
echo "Some text"
pwd
ls -la
echo "Starting script now . . ."
# This script can take a while, maybe 20 to 30 minutes
php ./some_long_running_script.php arg1 arg2
echo "Finished!"
```

The issue I'm having is that when the job runs it kills this bash script after some time. It is usually after 8 to 10 minutes, but it is *not consistent*.

When it kills, the following is output to the log:

```
/var/lib/rundeck/tmp-jobs/372376-1775772-my-server-com-staging2-dispatch-script.tmp.sh: line 13: 15425 Killed
```

Where `line 13` corresponds to the line number of the long running PHP script.

When I manually run the script on the same server node, I do not see this issue and the script runs to completion.

**Does Rundeck kill jobs/scripts that it thinks are taking too long?** The job level timeout is currently set to blank, which according to the documentation means *no timeout*.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you didn't set timeout in your job definition.

There is another timeout setting in Rundeck SSH plguin. You can set it in different level(node,project,rundeck)

For node level:

> `ssh-connection-timeout` connection timeout
>
> `ssh-command-timeout` command timeout

The default value is 0 (no timeout)

The config file is `framework.properties` under rundeck base dir

[Specifying SSH Timeout options](http://rundeck.org/docs/plugins-user-guide/ssh-plugins.html#specifying-ssh-timeout-options)